# Converge of Sum divide by log(n)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am trying to show that If

$b_n = \sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-1}) -\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-2})$ then $\frac{b_n}{\log(n)} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I start this problem by showing this inequality

$$\sum^n_{k=2}(k^{-1}) \leq \log(n) \leq \sum^{n-1}_{k=1}(k^{-1})$$
then as $k>0$
$$\frac{1}{\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}(k^{-1})} \leq \frac{1}{\log(n)} \leq \frac{1}{\sum^{n}_{k=2}(k^{-1})}$$
Now I am stuck how to break this division

$$
\frac{\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-1}) -\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-2})}{\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}(k^{-1})} \leq \frac{\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-1}) -\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-2})}{\log(n)}  \leq \frac{\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-1}) -\sum^n_{k=1}(k^{-2})}{\sum^{n}_{k=2}(k^{-1})}
$$

can you help please

Comment: Can you prove the sum of $k^{-2}$ converges?

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show $$\frac{b_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}}, \frac{b_n}{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}} \to 1$$ as $n \to \infty$.  But we can rewrite the first fraction as $$\frac{b_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} 1/k} = \frac{ 1 + 1/2 + \dots + 1/(n-1)}{1+1/2 + \dots + 1/(n-1)} + \frac{1/n  - \sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1/k^2}{1 + 1/2 + \dots + 1/(n-1)} = 1 + \frac{1/n - \sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1/k^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} 1/k}.$$  But as $n \to \infty$, the denominator of this final term diverges, and the numerator remains finite, so that $$\frac{b_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} 1/k} \to 1$$ as $n \to \infty$.  Modify this argument for the other term and you are done.